# DateTime compare in c# when i try to compare next year datetime

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I am comparing a user given date with  system.datetime in c#
if the date is passed or if the date matches the system.date time it is considered

```
if ((Convert.ToDateTime(firstTimeOFArray).ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy HH:mm").CompareTo(System.DateTime.Now.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy HH:mm")) == 0 ||
     Convert.ToDateTime(firstTimeOFArray).ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy HH:mm").CompareTo(System.DateTime.Now.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy HH:mm")) == -1))
{
    filenamedate = DR_FILENAME;
    fileFound = true;
}
```

my problem is if i give a date like 2016/12/22 3:00 pm  it will accept it  at exact 2016/12/22 3:00 pm at system time.

if the time is already passed like ex: system time is 2016/12/22 3:00 pm and user time is 2016/12/21 3:00 pm. the logic is accept.

but if i give the system time 2016/12/21 3:00 pm and user time 2017/12/21 3:00 pm.. it again accepts. ideally it should not until the sytem goes to that exact date in 2017.
where am i going wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this compare ?

Comment: Compare the `DateTime` objects themselves, not the result of converting them to `string`s.

Comment: if date is equal or less it should go in the loop, if date and year is  more if should not go in.

Comment: in case of 2017 it  goes inside the loop. which it should not

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
if ((Convert.ToDateTime(firstTimeOFArray).ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy HH:mm").CompareTo(System.DateTime.Now.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy HH:mm")) == 0 ||
     Convert.ToDateTime(firstTimeOFArray).ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy HH:mm").CompareTo(System.DateTime.Now.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy HH:mm")) == -1))
```

with this:

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(firstTimeOFArray) <= DateTime.Now)
```

which is probably what you meant. From then it will be much easier for you to understand the sematics of your own code and achieve what you want.

Note that for lexicographic comparison of string representations of two `DateTime`s would need the `yyyy MM dd HH mm` sequence of components in order to work.